# How to check completion of non-blocking reduce?

Tags: mpi

It is not clear to me how to properly use non-blocking collective in MPI, particularly `MPI_Ireduce()` in this case:

Say I want to collect a sum from root rank:

```
int local_cnt;
int total_cnt;
MPI_Request request;
MPI_Ireduce(&local_cnt, &total_cnt, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_WORLD_COMM, &request);

/* now I want to check if the reduce is finished */

if (rank == 0) {
    int flag = 0;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
    if (flag) {
        /* reduce is finished? */
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to check if non-blocking reduce is done? My confusion comes from two aspects: one, Can or should just root process check for it using `MPI_Test()` since this is meaningful only to root? second, since `MPI_Test()` is local op, how can this local op knows the operation is complete? it does require all processes to finish, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check for completion on **all participating ranks**, not just the root.

From a user perspective, you need to know about the completion of the communication because you must not do anything with the memory provided to a non-blocking operation. I.e. if you send a local scope variable like `local_cnt`, you cannot write to it or leave it's scope before you have confirmed that the operation is complete.

One option to ensure completion is calling `MPI_Test` until it eventually returns `flag==true`. Use this only if you can do something useful between the calls to `MPI_Test`:

```
{
    int local_cnt;
    int total_cnt;

    // fill local_cnt on all ranks

    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Ireduce(&local_cnt, &total_cnt, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_WORLD_COMM, &request);

    int flag;
    do {

        // perform some useful computation
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
    } while (!flag)
}
```

Do not call `MPI_Test` in a loop if you have nothing useful to do in between calls. Instead use `MPI_Wait`, which blocks until completion.

```
{
    int local_cnt;
    int total_cnt;

    // fill local_cnt on all ranks

    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Ireduce(&local_cnt, &total_cnt, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_WORLD_COMM, &request);

    // perform some useful computation
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
}
```

Remember, if you have no useful computation at all, and don't need to be non-blocking for deadlock reasons, use a blocking communication in the first place. If you have multiple ongoing non-blocking communication, there are `MPI_Waitany`, `MPI_Waitsome`, `MPI_Waitall` and their Test variant's.

Answer (score 1):

Zulan brilliantly answered the first part of your question.

`MPI_Reduce()` returns when

- the send buffer can be overwritten on a non root rank
- the result is available on the root rank (which implies all the ranks have completed)

So there is no way for a non root rank to know whether the root rank completed. If you do need this information, then you need to manually add a `MPI_Barrier()`. That being said, you generally do **not** require this information, and if you believe you do need it, there might be something wrong with your app.

This remains true if you use non blocking collectives (e.g. `MPI_Wait()` corresponding to `MPI_Ireduce()` completes on a non root rank : that simply means the send buffer can be overwritten.